# UITextView inside UICollectionViewCell insists on growing horizontally

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITextView inside my UICollectionView cell, and it keeps getting growing horizontally depending on its content. My collection view is set to be vertically scrolling, and the cells calculate their own size. I want my text view to grow vertically depending on its contents, not horizontally.

Here is my cell, text view, and their constraints:

[image]

[image]

Initially, compression resistance and hugging had default values, but as they didn't work, I've set horizontal hugging to 1000 and horizontal compression to 250 to keep my text view from growing. It doesn't seem to work as well.

No constraints are being broken, however, I'm constantly getting this message in the log:

```
Please check the values return by the delegate.
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values.
```

I think it's related. How can I keep my text view inside the defined bounds and make it grow vertically instead of horizontally.

**UPDATE:** It's not just growing by itself. Because of the constraints (and it's not breaking them), it's growing the whole cell. Notice right-aligned the time indicator "2h" is out of bounds at the screenshot from runtime:

[image]

Comment: Is it the text view that's growing horizontally, or the cell itself? The constraints you have shouldn't allow the text view to get wider, given a particular cell width.

Comment: You need to change your question then. It has nothing to do with the constraints you're showing, it has to do with the way you're sizing your cells. You need to show the code for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround/solution. While I still don't understand why a text view with required horizontal hugging priority was growing horizontally instead of vertically, I've added a width constraint programmatically to my cell, equal to the width of the screen, and it worked. It forces the cell and the text view to stay at their designated width, and any content wraps dynamically.